# Marginal PDF from a joint PDF with an integral that does not converge

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a joint PDF that has gone through some transformations of

$f(x,y) = 12x\displaystyle\frac{1-y}{y^3}$,$0<x<y^2$, $0<y<1$

It definitely is a valid PDF as it has a double integration along its support that equals 1

I am trying to find the marginal PDF of $X$.

However integrating along y gives a definite integral that does not converge:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 12x\displaystyle\frac{1-y}{x^3}dy$

Any ideas how else I can find that marginal PDF of $X$?

Comment: What are the limits on $x$ and $y$? Or in other words, what is the support?

Comment: Sorry I somehow cut that bit out.
0<x<y^2   and 0<y<1

Comment: Then, contrarily to what you declare in the post, if f is the density of a joint PDF, the integral over y should converge. Or rather, it should for almost every x. (Please check your post, at the moment the two formulas for f are not compatible.)

Comment: Draw a picture! Then integrate, $y=\sqrt{x}$ to $y=1$. No problem.

Comment: Didier
you can try to check, but this shows that it is a PDF http://bit.ly/KuqAK8
and this shows it does not converge
http://bit.ly/KlhM8C

Andre - Wouldn't I then be losing x values that are less than root x and greater than zero?

Comment: @Seraphya: In the second calculation, you gave the program the wrong integral, and it calculated correctly. I would rather you found the answer partly by yourself, so will wait a while before answering, in the hope you can push things through. The region in which the joint density lives is the first quadrant region that is below the line $y=1$ and **above** the curve $x=y^2$.  So when we "integrate $y$ out" the variable $y$ runs from $y=\sqrt{x}$ to $y=1$, **not** from $y=0$ to $y=1$. Remember the $0\lt x\lt y^2$, which in particular says that $y \gt\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @Seraphya: After you find the answer, send a message. I did the calculation, so can check whether you are right.

Comment: I see I should redefine the support as 0<x<y^2  and x^(1/2)<y<1

so -12*x^(1/2) + 6x +6 and 0<x<1

@André Nicolas Thanks!

Comment: @Seraphya: Yes, I also had $6+6x-12x^{1/2}$ over the same interval.  If you like, you can write up the answer reasonably carefully, and post it as the solution, and, after waiting a little while, accept it.

Comment: @AndreNicholas I get 6 + 6x -12 (x)^1/2 and my density g(x) integrates to 1 whereas 6+6x-12 integrates to -3.  Mine does look like Seraphyra's. Maybe something caused the square root of x to come up blank in Andre's post.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the probability density was clarified in the comments:
$$f(x,y) = 12x(1-y)y^{-3}\, [0<x<y^2 \text{ and }0<y<1]
$$ (using the Iverson bracket). To prepare integration along $y$, note that 
$$[0<x<y^2 \text{ and }0<y<1] = [\sqrt{x}<y<1 \text{ and }0<x<1]$$
Therefore,
$$\int f(x,y)\,dy = [0<x<1] \int_{\sqrt{x}}^1 12x(1-y)y^{-3} \,dy $$
which evaluates to $[0<x<1] \, (6+6x−12\sqrt{x}) $. This is the required marginal.

(Sanity check: the marginal integrates to $6+6/2-12/(3/2)=1$.)